# Tablayout com reyclerview no android

Tags: android

Estou com um problema referente a TabLayout e RecyclerView. Tenho algumas tabs que são preenchidas de acordo com o retorno de um arquivo json. Essas tabs são as categorias de produtos e de acordo com o clique do usuario é carregado dentro do recycler view um adapter com os produtos daquela categoria. Em cada item do recycler view tenho um produto e cada produto possui um simbolo de adicionar ou remover e possuo um textview que de acordo com o clique no mais ou menos é incrementado ou decrementado. Preciso que ao selecionar os produtos em uma tab, quando clicar em outra tab e depois voltar para a tab onde já existia produtos selecionados, os mesmos produtos já selecionados estejam lá. Vou colocar o código que já tentei até o momento.

```
public class Carrinho {

    private String id_produto;
    private String quantidade_produto;
    private String nome_produto;

    public String getNome_produto() {
        return nome_produto;
    }

    public void setNome_produto(String nome_produto) {
        this.nome_produto = nome_produto;
    }

    public String getId_produto() {
        return id_produto;
    }

    public void setId_produto(String id_produto) {
        this.id_produto = id_produto;
    }

    public String getQuantidade_produto() {
        return quantidade_produto;
    }

    public void setQuantidade_produto(String quantidade_produto) {
         this.quantidade_produto = quantidade_produto;
    }


}

public class CarrinhoController {

    private List<Carrinho> carrinhoList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Carrinho> getCarrinhoList() {
        return carrinhoList;
    }

    public void setCarrinhoList(List<Carrinho> carrinhoList) {
        this.carrinhoList = carrinhoList;
    }
}
```

Tentei criar essa estrutura dentro de uma lista e depois verifico dentro dela se existe produtos que também exista dentro da lista de produtos da tab atual, e se sim, colocaria o valor do text view daquele produto com a quantidade que vem da lista onde é adicionado os produtos.

Comment: Fala ai Guilherme, tem como postar o código da TabLayout e do RecyclerView?
Pelo oque eu entendi, o problema é que sempre que o usuário clickar numa tab, vc vai setar o adapter do recyclerview novamente, e isso vai desmarcar todas que já estavam marcadas. Você tem que criar um mecanismo de singleton pra instanciar o adapter apenas uma vez, e nas outras vezes apenas reutilizar essa instancia.

Comment: Opa Max, obrigado pela dica. Porém consegui resolver aqui utilizando lambdas do java 8. Faço da seguinte forma, faço uma comparação entre meu carrinho e os produtos que estão naquele adapter. Se o id do produto for igual, então significa que existe dentro do carrinho e ai seto o valor do text view com a quantidade que já está dentro do carrinho. Vou postar o código onde faço isso

Comment: Stream.of(CarrinhoController.getCarrinhoList()).filter(p -> p.getId_produto().equals(view.getIdProduto())).forEach(c ->                                                        produtos.setQtd_produto(String.valueOf(c.getQuantidade_produto())));